# Is it possible to draw figures through JavaScript inside an iPhone app?

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

It's too hard to draw good 2D figures/tables through Objective-C GUI library.

Is it possible to draw figures through JavaScript Framework inside an iPhone app?

I mean:

1. Pack JQuery into iPhone App
2. Dynamically create HTML file
3. Load the HTML file in UIWebView

Comment: 1,2, and 3 are all possible in iPhone. Its quite trivial actually.

Comment: Your question already contains an outline of the solution, so what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use HTML Canvas to draw the shapes. This article will give you a basic introduction: http://projects.joshy.org/presentations/HTML/CanvasDeepDive/presentation.html